# Is it possible to create a VRT file with ogr2ogr?

Tags: ogr, vrt

I want to create VRT files from ungridded .asc files ([example file](http://gis.arso.gov.si/lidar/dmr1/b_32/D48GK/GK1_444_106.asc)).

The VRT files should look like [this](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/vrt.html#example-odbc-point-layer):

```
<OGRVRTDataSource>
    <OGRVRTLayer name="worms">
        <SrcDataSource>ODBC:DISEASE,worms</SrcDataSource>
        <SrcLayer>worms</SrcLayer>
        <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
        <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
        <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="x" y="y"/>
    </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>
```

I can't seem to find a way to create these VRT files with an GDAL/OGR command. The error is "VRT driver has no vector capabilities."
But when I create the VRT file manually (edit the text in an existing VRT file), it works fine.

Comment: See https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/vrt.html `The virtual files are currently normally prepared by hand.`

Answer (score 3):

An `.asc` file is usually an ESRI ASCII Grid file (a raster format) so if you change the extension to `.csv` you stand a better chance of reading them in.

You won't be able to write them out as a VRT because that is a Read Only (ro) format:

```
OGR_VRT -vector- (rov): VRT - Virtual Datasource
```

Something like:

```
ogr2ogr test.shp GK1_444_106.csv -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=field_1 -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=field_2 -oo KEEP_GEOM_COLUMNS=NO
```

gives:

```
ogrinfo -so -al test.shp
INFO: Open of `test.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.

Layer name: test
Metadata:
  DBF_DATE_LAST_UPDATE=2021-03-12
Geometry: Point
Feature Count: 1000361
Extent: (444000.000000, 106000.150000) - (444999.980000, 106999.150000)
Layer SRS WKT:
(unknown)
field_3: String (80.0)
```

Of course better output formats than Shapefile are available, and there is no way your input data is in EPSG:4326 so you'll want a `-s_srs epsg:...` in there too.

Comment: No need to change the extension. Can use "CSV:GK1_444_106.asc" to force use of CSV driver.